# Python Boolean logic chain

Tags: python

So, I am trying to put this Boolean logic table into python to give us an out put for x (end of logic table) https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pc113.jpg

my code thus far is:

```
#Main instructions
A = input('Enter 0 or 1 for 1st input: ')

B = input('Enter 0 or 1 for 2nd input: ')

C = input ('Enter 0 or 1 for 3rd input: ')

print 'The logic diagram, LOGIC-1 evaluates for the input values, A, B and C to X'

print "input 1 =",A

print "input 2 =",B

print "input 3 =",C

print (A and not B) and (not B or C)
```

However, the output is not aligning with my inputs. For example, input 0,0,0 gives 0. But I want it to be 1. Also, input 1,1,1 gives false.

Comment: Why 0,0,0 should be 1?

Comment: Irrelevant to the value of C, X = 1 iff A = 1 and B = 0.

Comment: `>>> (False and not False) and (not False or False)` returns `False`. Idem for `>>> (True and not True) and (not True or True)`. I don't think there is a problem for your code.

Comment: The output aligns with your inputs, just not your *expectation* of what the output should be.  (0,0,0) gives 0.

Comment: thanks for the input I think I may have made a mistake calculating by hand through logic table.

Comment: Look at the LOGIC-1 diagram.  The value `A` goes through two `AND` gates.  Therefore, any time `A` is 0, the output `X` will be 0 as well.  The correct output from 0,0,0 is 0.  In case this is not clear: the result of anything `AND` 0 is always 0.  Thus the output of the first `AND` gate must be 0 when `A` is 0.  Then that zero output goes into another `AND` gate, so it doesn't then matter what input comes from the `OR` gate, as anything `AND` 0 will be 0.

Comment: Assuming you use Python3: the function `input()` returns a string, you might have to convert that to a boolean first.

Comment: If you are on python2 you should really use `int(raw_input(...))` to get the input.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks okay.  I think you made some mistake evaluating the logic by hand.  Here's how to work through it:

- Start with "`A B C`"
- Rewrite to "`A N C`" where column `N` is "`NOT B`"
- Compute "`A AND N`" (use '`&`' to indicate `AND`)
- Compute "`N OR C`" (use '`|`' to indicate `OR`)
- Finally, compute final output value.

Like this:

```
A B C   A N C   A&N  N|C    (A&N)&(N|C)
0 0 0   0 1 0     0    1              0
0 0 1   0 1 1     0    1              0
0 1 0   0 0 0     0    0              0
0 1 1   0 0 1     0    1              0
1 0 0   1 1 0     1    1              1
1 0 1   1 1 1     1    1              1
1 1 0   1 0 0     0    0              0
1 1 1   1 0 1     0    1              0
```

And when I run a loop checking this with Python, I get the same answers I got by hand here.